# Performing SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF with two different tables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two tables

**TABLE 1:** 
Unit (Column 1): aa; bb; cc; dd,
Reliability (Column 2): 90%; 40%; 100%; 2%

**TABLE 2:**
Prod (Column 1): A; B; C; A; A,
Unit (Column 2): aa; bb; cc; bb; dd,
Tonnes (Column 3): 10; 20; 30; 40; 30

For product A, how do I calculate the total amount produced from units aa, bb and dd, taking into account the reliability in **a single formula**?

The calculation for tonnes of A is clear: `10 * 90% + 40 * 40% + 30 * 2%` but it is difficult to do this when the data is in a random order as mine is.

I suspect that SUMPRODUCT or SUMIF may be required. I'm quite good at Excel and genuinely think this is impossible so good luck.

**EDIT: I must state that I want to use a single formula, no additional columns to facilitate the calculation.**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a single result for **A**, how do you expect to show that without having an additional column or table showing the unique list of products???

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit clunky and uses two helper columns as you can see (can combine these if you wish), then you use sumifs() as shown:

[image]

The formulae in cols G and H are shown below the data, the formula in K2 is in L2...

Comment: Thank you for response, but I wish to use no additional columns.

Comment: Then you can investigate putting the calculations shown into one with the sumifs... As your original post said it was impossible - I have shown that it is possible, now adding further conditions is a different situation...

Comment: How does one put column H into the formula in L2?

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how you want the results displayed.

Adding a column to your `Table2` for the total, you can use this **array** formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,N(IF(1,MATCH(IF([@Prod]=[Prod],[Unit]),Table1[Unit],0))),2),0)*(([Prod]=[@Prod])*[Tonnes]))
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

If you want to create a separate table for the results, you can adapt the formula given.

For example, if I9 contains the Prod name, then:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,N(IF(1,MATCH(IF(I9=Table2[Prod],Table2[Unit]),Table1[Unit],0))),2),0)*((Table2[Prod]=I9)*Table2[Tonnes]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't believe this gives me the desired result. And also uses an additional table which I would not like to do.

Comment: @aoken_1 I misinterpreted your question prior to your edit.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I think you've cracked it. Just to confirm @Prod is the Product Array, right? I.n fact, I'm not quite sure what the square brackets mean either..

Comment: @aoken_1 No.  The square brackets are parts of `Structured References`.  You mentioned you had `Table`s, so I assumed that is what you had and used the appropriate references.  A reference like `@Prod` would refer to the "same row, same table, `Prod` column".  Take a look at [Using Structured References with Excel Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: Okay, just to confirm. Are you sure that you've typed the correct formula above..?

Comment: @aoken_1 Are the results in the screenshot correct?

Comment: Touche, yes they are but I can't seem to get the results you're getting the formula won't execute. For the Unit and Prod arrays do you have to define the columns. If you could be so kind as to send me your Excel file at acokenyi@gmail.com, I'd be very happy.

Comment: @aoken_1 sent via email.